# context api - loop in context data

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I have a code that I pass one name each time from parent component to the child using context API
but I don't figure how to loop on the context that I get from the provider and multiple the

tag each time I get name from the provider

where I put the loop ? and how I use JSX for multiple the

bullet
my code is this  for the child(consumer)

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import GrandChildComp_3 from './Demo3_GrandechildComp';
import myContext from './AppContext';
class ChildComp_3 extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <myContext.Consumer>
        {(context) => (
          <div className="App">
            <h2>Child_3 comp</h2>
            Name :{' '}
            <ul>
              <li>{context.name}</li>
            </ul>
            <GrandChildComp_3 />
          </div>
        )}
      </myContext.Consumer>
    );
  }
}
export default ChildComp_3;
```

and this is the code for the provider

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ChildComp_3 from './Demo3_childComp';
import myContext from './AppContext';

class ParentsComp_3 extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { name: [], age: [], name_arr: '', age_arr: '' };
  }
  getName = (e) => {
    this.setState({ name_arr: e.target.value });
  };
  getAge = (e) => {
    this.setState({ age_arr: e.target.value });
  };
  click = () => {
    //name
    let Name = this.state.name;
    let N = this.state.name_arr;
    Name.push(N);
    this.setState({ name: Name });
    //age
    let Age = this.state.age;
    let A = this.state.age_arr;
    Age.push(A);
    this.setState({ age: Age });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <myContext.Provider value={{ name: this.state.name, age: this.state.age }}>
        <div className="App">
          <h2>ParentsComp_3 comp</h2>
          Name : <input type="text" onChange={this.getName}></input>
          <br />
          Age: <input type="text" onChange={this.getAge}></input>
          <br />
          <input type="button" value="add" onClick={this.click}></input>
          <ChildComp_3 name={this.state.name} />
        </div>
      </myContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
export default ParentsComp_3;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to map the array of names to display them.

```
...
<ul>
  {
     name.map(n => <li>Name: {n}</li>
  }
</ul>
```

On another note, since you are passing these values to the child component you don't need to use the Context API. You can directly pass them as props to the child components like you have done here, but you haven't used the prop in ChildComp_3.

```
<ChildComp_3 name={this.state.name} />
```

Comment: i need use Context api because i need to pass data to grandechild to

Comment: but you'r answer was every helpful 
thank u very much!